# How should I approach this relations in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've been going back and forward on this and I would like some advices.

I have "User" that can be part of many "Organizations", and for each one they can have many "Roles". (actually I have this scenario repeated with other kind of users and with something like roles, but for the sake of the example I summed it up).

My initial approach was doing a Table with user_id, organization_id and role_id, but that would mean many registers with the same user_id and organization_id just to change the role_id.

So I thought of doing an organization_users relation table and an organization_users_roles relation. The thing is, now I don't exactly know how to code the models.

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users, join_table: :organization_users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :organizations, join_table: :organization_users
end

class OrganizationUser < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
   has_and_belongs_to_many :organizations
   has_many :organization_user_roles
   has_many :roles, through: :organization_user_roles
end

class OrganizationUserRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  has_and_belongs_to_many :organization_users
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :organization_user_roles
end
```

If for example I want to get: ´OrganizationUser.first.roles´ I get an error saying: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "organization_user_roles" does not exist

How should I fix my models?

Answer (score 3):

You should use a much simpler approach. According to your description, `Roles` is actually what connects `Users` to `Organizations` and vice-versa.

Using the `has_many` and `has_many :through` associations, this can be implemented like the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, inverse_of: :users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :organizations, inverse_of: :users, through: :roles
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, inverse_of: :organizations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, inverse_of: :organizations, through: :roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :roles
  belongs_to :organization, inverse_of: :roles
end
```

If you wish to preserve roles when you destroy users or organizations, change the `dependent:` keys to `:nullify`. This might be a good idea if you add other descriptive data in your `Role` and want the role to remain even though temporarily vacated by a user, for example.

The `has_many :through` association reference:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have mentioned that there are more scoped queries by a given Organization. For example a User may have Articles for a given Organization, as he may have Comments for a given Article that of course are scoped by Organization. Can this be done with this approach?

Comment: Yes it can. Although this is beyond the scope of your original question, the actual design implementation would be done based on a few key decisions: 1. When you say a User has Articles **for** an Organization, do you mean the Articles are **about** the Organization, or that the User has written the Article under a Role capacity that connects him/her to the Organization, or a mix of both? 2. Same thing with Comments.

Answer (score 2):

To add to `jaxx`'s answer (I upvoted), I originally thought you'd be best looking at [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association):

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :positions
   has_many :organizations, through: :positions
end

#app/models/position.rb
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | user_id | organization_id | role_id | etc | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :organization

   belongs_to :role
   delegate :name, to: :role #-> @position.name
end

#app/models/organization.rb
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :positions
   has_many :users, through: :positions
end

#app/models/role.rb
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :positions
end
```

This will allow you to call the following:

```
@organization = Organization.find x
@organization.positions
@organization.users

@user = User.find x
@user.organizations
@user.positions
```

---

This is much simpler than your approach, and therefore has much more ability to keep your system flexible & extensible.

If you want to scope your `@organizations`, you should be able to do so, and still call the `users` / `positions` you need.

One of the added benefits of the code above is that the `Position` model will give you an actual set of data which can be shared between `organizations` and `users`.

It resolves one of the main issues with `jaxx`'s answer, which is that you have to set a role for every association you make. With my interpretation, your `roles` can be set on their own, and each *position* assigned the privileges each role provides.

Comment: This is a very nice addition indeed, as it abstracts roles. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

If the user can have many `Roles` for a single organisation, 
and `OrganizationUser` represents this membership, 
than, yes, you need another table for `organization_user_roles`.

You need to explicitly create it in the database (normally with a migration)

To not get confused, try to find a nice name for `OrganisationUser`, like employment, membership, etc.